# Perron-Frobenius theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

In the proof of the Perron-Frobenius theorem why can we take a strictly positive eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$? Before that, why can we even take a non-negative eigenvector?

Books simply take such a vector, no explanation whatsoever. Pisses me off.

Wikipedia only proves it assuming the matrix is irreducible.

Any help? Thanks.

EDIT: Nevermind, got it. Delete this question, please.

Comment: Maybe you are reading the wrong books.

Comment: Geoff is correct.  For example H. Minc, *Nonnegative Matrices* has complete explanations.

Comment: I can't find that book on pdf.

Can you please just tell me why I can take a non-negative eigenvector? I think I can manage with the rest.

Comment: You people don't cease to amaze me. This is statistics, why would you two know anything about this?

I'm not being sarcastic. I'm constatly amazed by how smart people on this site are.

Comment: There are statisticians here too :-).

Comment: @Guy: Perron Frobenius has lots of other interesting applications besides to Statistics, though doubly stochastic matrices are certainly one natural place to use it.

Answer (score 16):

It really depends on how your book does it.

The easiest way I know of, is to consider the simplex $S = \{ (x_i) | x_i \geq 0, \sum x_i = 1\} $, and consider the action of the matrix $M$ on this simplex given by $M(s) = Ms / ||Ms||$ (i.e. normalize it such that it lies back in the simplex).

This gives us a map of the simplex to the simplex, hence has a fixed point by Brouwer's fixed point theorem. It remains to show that the boundary of this simplex is not a fixed point, because the entries of the matrix are all positive. Hence, the fixed point lies in the interior, and corresponds to the eigenvector that you're looking for.

Note that this doesn't prove the uniqueness, nor that the corresponding eigenvalue has strictly largest norm.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, but I got it now.

Thanks anyway, mate.

Comment: Brouwer seems like big guns here. Is there a simpler proof using the fact that M maps the positive cone into itself? If a matrix maps a closed convex cone into itself, must it have an eigenvector in the cone?

Comment: @copper.hat The map is a [strict contraction mapping](http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/kohlberg-contraction.pdf). Is that simple enough for you? I think that Brouwer is very basic though.

Comment: Assuming the entries of the matrix are all positive is not the most  general form of the Perron Frobenius Theorem. Such a matrix would be irreducible according to the definition given in Wikipedia, for example. That may be part of the problem, since here are many versions of the theorem in the literature, and it is not clear (to me at least) which version Guy is working with.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Nice article, thanks. (While the statement is easy, I have never seen a proof of Brouwer's theorem that I would consider basic.)

Comment: I like Wielandt's proof of Perron Frobenius personally.

Comment: @CalvinLin Why do you need the fixed point not to be on the boundary of the simplex? thank you!

Comment: @Moritzplatz Only because the question also want the coordinate to be strictly positive. If you don't care about that, then you don't have to check the boundary.

Comment: ah yeah, didn't read the question carefully! thanks