# How prove this matrix have a positive eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}&a_{2}&a_{3}\\
a_{4}&a_{5}&a_{6}\\
a_{7}&a_{8}&a_{9}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $a_{i}>0$,

show that the matrix $A$ At least one
  positive eigenvalue。

I think this problem is very interesting,and I can't prove it,Thank you

It is said this problem can be proved by Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem： http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20002.7.shtml
and it's very nice, who can see it? Thank you.

and I think this problem can be solved using linear-algebra methods.Thank you

Comment: See [Calvin's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/268899/1551) in a related thread.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take $S=\{x\in \Bbb R^3: \forall i\,x_i\ge 0,\,x_1+x_2+x_3=1 \}$. Then the image of $S$ under transformation $A$ is still in $\Bbb R_+^3$. We take a projection $P:x\to \frac{x}{x_1+x_2+x_3}$, thus we obtain the application $P\circ A:S\to S$. This application has a fixed point by Brouwer's theorem, which gives you the eigenvector, obviously corresponding to a positive eigenvalue.

Comment: You can not apply Brouwer's theorem to $S$ as $S$ is open and homeomorphic to an open disc. Use the closure of $S$ instead. Its image under $A$ also lies in $\mathbb{R}^{3}_{+}$.

Comment: @posilon Indeed, thanks for the catch. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy- We have found a fixed point, and hence eigenvector for $P\circ A$, and not $A$. How can we conclude anything about the eigenvectors or eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Note that for any vector $x\in S$ the vectors $Ax$ and $(P\circ A)x$ are colinear.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy- Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Just a small comment to add some explicitness: $P(x):=x/(x_1+x_2+x_3)=:x/\lambda$, so for some $x\in S$, the Brouwer Theorem says that when restricting $P\circ A$ to $S$, then there is an $x$ s.t. $x=P(A(x))=A(x)/\lambda$, so this $x$ is the eigenvector and $\lambda>0$ because $|x|>0$.

Answer (score 5):

Everything you need is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

In a nutshell, the Perron-Frobenius theorem states that such a positive eigenvalue exists, and more specifically that there is only one eigenvalue with maximal modulus, which is real>0.

Comment: Thank you, But I can't find your link solution with my problem.and I hope see this problem have nice and simple methods.

Comment: You just need item 1 here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices

Comment: You can read this for a proof that the spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$: http://www.matrixanalysis.com/Chapter8.pdf

Comment: Thank you  very much    +1.

Answer (score -1):

The trace of the matrix Tr$({\bf A})$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, and also the sum of the diagonals under any transformation. Since the sum of the diagonals is greater than zero, at least one eigenvalue must be greater than zero.

Comment: if eigenvalues is complex? This is not true

Comment: You said the matrix elements were greater than zero. How am I to interpret this is they are complex? What does "positive" even mean if they are complex?

Comment: I said exsit at least one positive  eigenvalue

Comment: I quote "If $a_i >0$" (the matrix elements are greater than zero) "show that the matrix $A$ has at least one positive eigenvalue." This is a proof. If the numbers are complex, then you must specify what you mean by $a_i>0$. Are both the real and imaginary parts greater than zero? Just the real part?

Comment: ... I think you don't understand my question,,I mean this eigenvalue maybe have complex..for example: three eigenvalue is$$1+2i,1-2i,-1$$

Comment: You're right, I assumed the eigenvalues were real. This answer is wrong, sorry about that.