# Proving Matrix properties in conjunction with eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-characteristic

Why is the following statement true?

**If all entries in a Matrix $K=A^TA=AA^T$ are greater than or equal to 0, then the highest eigenvalue has a  corresponding eigenvector whose entries are also greater than or equal to 0.**

Answer (score 1):

This is part of what is known as [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem). The (real and nonnegative) eigenvalue that is equal to the spectral radius of $K$ is called the *Perron eigenvalue*, and any nonnegative eigenvector (usually normalised so that the sum of all elements, rather than the Euclidean norm, is equal to $1$) corresponding to this eigenvalue is called a *Perron vector*.

Showing that the Perron eigenvalue exists is relatively easy (e.g. see the above Wikipedia entry). The difficult part is to prove the existence of a Perron vector. When $K$ is [doubly stochastic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix), the Perron eigenvalue is $1$ and the existence of a Perron vector is trivial: just take the all-one vector. If $K$ is entrywise positive and you only want to prove that there exists an entrywise positive eigenvector corresponding to *some* positive eigenvalue, there is also a simple proof (see [Calvin Lin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268899/1551), for instance). Yet, for the general case, I am not aware of any simple proof of the existence of Perron vector.