# In a positive Markov matrix, why is the eigenvector corresponding to λ = 1 non-zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a theorem I've seen in multiple places, but haven't been able to find a proof of. Is it because all of the eigenvectors are non-zero? What's the intuition behind it?

Comment: conservation of total probability

Comment: In short: eigenvectors are supposed to be nonzero in general, but in the case of a regular markov chain, the eigenvector in question gives direct information about the equilibrium (steady state vector) of the system. Obviously (ahum!) that cannot be represented by the zero vector. Have you taken a course that covers Markov or are you currently taking it?

Comment: But .. is there some math to demonstrate that?

Comment: that is a part of the definition of eigenvector, as for **every** $\lambda$ we have $A0 = \lambda 0 = 0$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confusing a nonzero eigenvector with an **entrywise** nonzero eigenvector.

Every eigenvector is nonzero by definition, but not every eigenvector is entrywise nonzero (counterexample: consider any diagonal matrix of size $>1$ with distinct diagonal entries).

A positive Markov matrix does possess an entrywise nonzero eigenvector, however. Actually we can do better: every positive Markov matrix $M$ has left and right **entrywise positive** eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.

Without loss of generality, suppose all column sums of $M$ are equal to $1$. Then $M$ of course possess an entrywise positive left eigenvector $e^T=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. The remaining question is whether $M$ has an entrywise positive right eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$. One simple classical proof (as mentioned by Calvin Lin in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268899)) of this fact is to note that the function $f(x)=Mx/\|Mx\|_1$ maps the simplex $S=\{x\ge0: \sum_ix_i=1\}$ into itself, and hence by Brouwer's fixed-point theorem, it has a fixed point in $S$. As $x\in S$, it is entrywise nonnegative. However, since $M$ is positive, $f(x)=x$ can only occur only when $x$ is entrywise positive. Finally, as
$$
1=e^Tx=(e^TM)x=e^T(Mx)=e^T(\|Mx\|_1x)=\|Mx\|_1,
$$
we see that $x$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$.

There is actually an even stronger result, namely, the celebrated Perron-Frobenius theorem, which implies that the eigenvalue $1$ is also simple, so that $x$ is unique up to scaling. I shall not go into details here, as the complete statement of Perron-Frobenius theorem is quite involved, and you can find it easily in any good reference books with chapters on nonnegative matrices.

Answer (score 0):

An eigenvector is non-zero **by definition**.